# maven plugin for eclipse, proxy issue

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy, dependencies, m2eclipse

I use m2eclipse to integrate Eclipse (Indigo) and Maven. I also use a proxy, so I have a Settings.xml with the correct host and port. I've configured the LAN Settings of the OS too, so Eclipse is configured in the same way (Native mode). Finally, I have put an external maven as the Eclipse installation (Maven 2.2.1) .

Once I did that, I import from Eclipse a Maven project. When I do "mvn install" the artifacts are downloaded, and I get the "Build Succesfull". However, the project marks an error.

The error type is different if is a project with dependencies (pom dependencies) or a simple project. For example, in a simple project the error is "Could not calculate build plan: connection timed out". In a complex project doesn't read some artifacts, which are in the repository.

I think the problem is the plugin and the proxy because in the console appears when eclipse starts, "Unable to update index for central http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/".

Any idea?

Thank you for your help

Ángel

Answer (score 5):

Since your build is working fine I believe your `setting.xml` is maven installation folder is working fine.

So try to change the maven setting in eclipse as shown below and refer the same `setting.xml` that is there in the maven folder configuration.

[image: Maven setting eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

Not a very helpful answer, but I ran into the same problem.
m2eclipse didn't seem to handle proxies (either eclipse or .settings) very well.

My workaround at the time was to always have a command line handy to pull in new dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Maven error: `Could not calculate build plan: connection timed out`

What finally fixed it was a **complete Clean and Rebuild**:

Project > Clean... 
  (x) Clean all projects  
  (x) Build the entire workspace